# Spring REST (MVC). How to modify http request before handling in the controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'd like to ask. How to modify http request before handling in the Spring REST (MVC) controller?

As far as I found I can make with servlets through filter and custom request wrapper. So does anyone know how to make it in Spring (e.g. via interceptors)?

My aim is to add new request parameter to request to use it into controller

Thx in advance

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to achieve? Adding a parameter to a request sounds like a very bad idea to me, and there is probably a much better way to solve the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @b3lowster, what you have tried? put some code here.

Comment: Let me explain what I want to achieve. In the controller I have a few endpoints and several of them expect a non-mandatory parameter (let's assume the parameter has name "type"). So I want to fill this parameter in AOP-style when parameter value is null (but not through default value).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Filter to modify httprequestparameter value.  Watchout the implementation:

Web.xml

```
<filter>
    <description>check request for service token</description>
    <filter-name>CustomFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.filters.CustomFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CustomFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Create a Filter Class:

```
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

    String encoding;
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");

        if (encoding == null) {
            encoding = "UTF-8";
        }
    }    

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // next handler 
        System.out.println("accessed");
        filterChain.doFilter(new CustomFilterWrapper((HttpServletRequest)request),(HttpServletResponse)response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }    
}
```

Create a CustomFilterWrapper where you override getParameter method to modify certain request parameter. In my case I change value if the request param is maverick.

```
public class CustomFilterWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    public CustomFilterWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(String name) {


        String[] vals = getParameterMap().get(name);

        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("maverick")) {
            return "modify value";

        } else if (vals != null && vals.length > 0) {
            return vals[0];
        } else {
            return null;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I know how it works. It's not a problem for me at all. In this way I cannot add new parameter or change existed from the request